# Function name must be string on Calculation in PHP function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to do a calculation in my code and it comes up with an error of

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string on line 3


function compound_interest($compound_interest, $compound_interest_f, $investment, $interest_rate, $years, $compoundMonthly, $future_value_f, $future_value) {
    if (isset($compoundMonthly)) {
        $compoundMonthly = 'Yes';
        $compound_interest = ($investment(1 + $interest_rate / 12)^(12 * $years) - $investment);
        $compound_interest_f = '$' . number_format($compound_interest, 2);
        return $compound_interest_f;
    } else {
        $compoundMonthly = 'No';
       $future_value = ($future_value + ($future_value * $interest_rate * .01));
        $future_value_f = '$' . number_format($future_value, 2);
        return $future_value_f;
    }
}
```

Only the code on that line is trying to do a calculation. Not print a string. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: What calculation is `$investment(1 + $interest_rate / 12)` supposed to do? You need an arithmetic operator between them.

Comment: Without an operator, it looks like you're trying to call `$investment` as a function.

Comment: Also, `^` is not exponentiation in PHP, you need to call the `pow()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `*` operator for multiplication; without this, you're trying to call `$investment` as a function, but it contains a number. And you need to use the `pow()` function to do exponentiation; `^` is bit-wise XOR.

```
$compound_interest = $investment * pow((1 + $interest_rate / 12), 12 * $years) - $investment;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking literal math there. hah! Nice answer!